How can I get Angular to let me import CSS files in TypeScript?
TL;DR:
I need the Angular compiler to let me import CSS files in Typescript and turn them into <style> tags in the head.
Background:
I'm migrating an existing React app over to Angular. Each React component will eventually be rewritten, but in the meantime I'm hosting them in Angular components based on this method: https://medium.com/@joseph5/rendering-react-component-in-angular-apps-9154fa3198d1.
Each React component imports its own CSS programmatically in the .tsx:
import "./MyComponent.css";

This works fine when they're running in the original React app, but Angular doesn't like it. Instead of rendering a <style> tag in the head like the React app does, Angular just ignores the import with no effect that I can see.
The obvious solution is to import it into the Angular host component's .scss:
@import 'react/MyComponent/MyComponent';

The problem here is that these React components have children, grandchildren, etc, and each imports its own stylesheet. I have to dig through all of them and make sure each is imported by the Angular component. It's a huge pain to dig through everything recursively and maybe miss one. It would be extremely helpful if I could get Angular to process the existing import statements from the .tsx the same way React does, by adding a style tag in the head. Is there any way I can do this?

Generally you can include the CSS file as part of your component's decorator definition:
@Component({
  selector: 'my-page',
  templateUrl: './my-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-page.component.css'],
})
export class MyPageComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

Global CSS can get added as part of your angular.json config:
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
           ...

My Angular project doesn't use standalone components, so I don't know if that would change anything.

This still leaves me with the same problem of having to manually dig through the children and grandchildren of every React component and make sure all their stylesheets are included in the top-level Angular host. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

If you are upgrading every component to use Angular then you can use the styleUrls approach to import each stylesheet at a component-level.

I'm not. I only need to host React components with their own route. Those components import their own child components, but they don't need separate Angular components to host them.
